# Learning XQuery() in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery-sql

SQL server 2008 sp2

I am a beginner and finding that XQuery syntax especially XPath very challenging.
For e.g. trying to use various xml methods like exists(), nodes(), value() etc….

Is there a good tutorial online or book you recommnded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I found the [XQuery Labs](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/06/26/xquery-labs-a-collection-of-xquery-sample-scripts.aspx) at [Beyondrelational.com](http://beyondrelational.com) very useful also add the following links to your bookmarks:

- [XML Data Modification Language (XML DML) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx)
- [XQuery Language Reference (Database Engine) (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)